# Removing unwanted data in MIME Java

Tags: java, performance, jakarta-mail, mime, mime-mail

I have MIME data with following unwanted data(asdfasfa -) . What is the best way to remove this unwanted data from MIME ?

```
asdfasfaDate: ****
From: ****
To: ****
Message-Id: ****
Subject: ****
MIME-Version: 1.0
```

Any help?

Comment: Where is the MIME data stored and what do you mean by "remove"?  At one level this is just a string manipulation problem.  Are you asking how to use String.indexOf and String.substring?

Comment: I have java app where i will get mail from third-party app. I am getting that <asdfasfa> unwanted character from the email sent from third-party app. Those mails are rejected by few mail servers. If i remove that <asdfasfa> data, it will be proper MIME then.

Comment: Well of course it might be worthwhile figuring out why that garbage is added to the message to begin with!  :-)  If the message comes as a file, and the garbage is always at the beginning of the file, it would be easy to skip over it when reading the file, and then pass the remainder of the InputStream to the MimeMessage constructor.  If the message is stored in a mail server with the bogus header, you can read the message using JavaMail, use the MimeMessge copy constructor to make a writable copy of the message, remove the bogus header, and add a new Date header with the correct value.